# Conversion from Seq to Set and back to Seq

Tags: scala

Intuitively the following should work:

```
case class I(i: Int)
val s = Seq(I(1),I(2),I(3))
s.sortBy(_.i)             // works
s.toSeq.sortBy(_.i)       // works
s.toSet.toSeq.sortBy(_.i) // doesn´t work
```

Why doesn´t it behave as expected?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a complicated impact of mixing covariant and invariant collections.  Set is invariant: `Set[A]`.  But Seq is covariant: `Seq[+A]`.  Now, imagine you want to have a `toSet` method in your Seq.  You might try `toSet: Set[A]`.  But this isn't going to work, because if `A` is a subclass of `B`, then `Seq[A]` should be considered as a subclass of `Seq[B]`.  However, `Seq[A]` insists on returning a `Set[A]` which is *not* a subclass of `Seq[B]`.  So our typing is broken.

If, on the other hand, we specify `toSeq[B >: A]: Set[B]` then everything is fine: if we promise we can return any superclass, then `Seq[A]` can return `Set[B]` as well as `Set[C]` where `C` is a superclass of `B`.  `Seq[B]` promised to return `Set[B]` or some `Set[C]` also, so we're in the clear: the method on `Seq[A]` can do everything that the method on `Seq[B]` can do.

But now look at what the poor typer is faced with:

```
s.toSet[B >: I]
 .toSeq/* Type B >: I*/
 .sortBy[C](/* some f:B => C */)(/* implicit ordering on C */)
```

There *is* a way to resolve this--namely to decide that `B` is `I` and type the function and `C` accordingly.  But it gets to be a pretty complicated search, and it's more than the compiler can handle right now.  So it asks you to help it out with the input type to the function so it knows `B` at that point (and then can propagate it back to `toSet`).

But you can, if you want, help it out at a number of levels:

```
s.toSet[I].toSeq.sortBy(_.i)
s.toSet.toSeq.sortBy[Int](_.i)
```

or you can help it out by demonstrating to it that it need not consider later types when picking the best match with earlier types:

```
{ val temp = s.toSet; temp }.toSeq.sortBy(_.i)
s.toSet match { case x => x.toSeq.sortBy(_.i) }
```

Comment: Rex, thanks for that enlightenment, that´s what I wanted. Such answers not only solves the problem, it also gives me a deeper understanding what´s happening. Thank you very much! What a pity, one can only upvote once :D

Answer (score 0):

It looks like about something to do with type inference, I don't know quite well.

But both of following do the trick:

```
s.toSet.toSeq.asInstanceOf[Seq[I]].sortBy(_.i)
s.toSet.toSeq.sortWith(_.i < _.i)
```

Comment: Yes, I know how to overcome the problem, but why does it persist in my case? It isn´t intuitively.